# JSONP response for Kendo UI does not populate grid

Tags: php, jsonp, kendo-grid

Please give me your advice.

The following URL gives jsonp formatted data:
http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products

However, only change I made was use my own url pointing to simple php to get jsonp data as below:

```
<?php
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
header('Content-Length: 1743');
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8');
echo gzencode('callback([{"ProductID":2,"ProductName":"Chang","UnitPrice":19,"UnitsInStock":17,"Discontinued":false}])');
?>
```

The HTML source is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ESS Software Inventory</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="./kendoui/content/shared/styles/examples-offline.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./kendoui/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./kendoui/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./kendoui/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="./kendoui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./kendoui/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./kendoui/content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    </script>    
</head>

<body>
    
        <a class="offline-button" href="../index.html">Back</a>
    
            <div id="example" class="k-content">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
          var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://dnettools/essinventory/cgi-bin",
                    //var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read:  {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/products.php",
                   //url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/products.php",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/products.php",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/products.php",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        navigatable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 430,
                        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                        columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 110 },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: 110 },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 90 }],
                        editable: true
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to use this: since the returned jsonp should have dynamic callback name

```
 parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);  <br/>  echo &quot;$callback&quot; . '([{&quot;ProductID&quot;:1,&quot;ProductName&quot;:&quot;Chai&quot;,&quot;UnitPrice&quot;:18,&quot;UnitsInStock&quot;:39,&quot;Discontinued&quot;:false},{&quot;ProductID&quot;:2,&quot;ProductName&quot;:&quot;Chang&quot;,&quot;UnitPrice&quot;:19,&quot;UnitsInStock&quot;:17,&quot;Discontinued&quot;:false},{&quot;ProductID&quot;:3,&quot;ProductName&quot;:&quot;Aniseed Syrup&quot;,&quot;UnitPrice&quot;:10,&quot;UnitsInStock&quot;:13,&quot;Discontinued&quot;:false},{&quot;ProductID&quot;:4,&quot;ProductName&quot;:&quot;Chef Anton\u0027s Cajun Seasoning&quot;,&quot;UnitPrice&quot;:22,&quot;UnitsInStock&quot;:53,&quot;Discontinued&quot;:false}])';
```